# Quick way to extract a substring from a string in Ruby using any method

Tags: ruby, string, substring

As a beginner in Ruby, how can I extract a substring from within a string in Ruby?

Example:

```
string1 = "1.1.67.01-f9@92a47088f49d095f0"
```

I want to extract substring from the beginning to '-'.  So the substring is '1.1.67.01'

Comment: Regular expressions are usually the answer for such kind of problems, but in you case it can be as simple as `prefix, _ = string1.split('-')` (`prefix` contains the desired substring then)

Comment: If the string may contain multiple hyphens it would be slightly more efficient to write `prefix, _ = string1.split('-', 2)`, which splits the string on the first hyphen only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the first `-` appears following your desired substring, [Ruby’s string split](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) method is a good candidate for this. This’d look something like:

```
string1.split('-')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one uses the index of the first `-` to slice the string (0 being the start of the string):

```
substring = string1[0, string1.index("-")]
```

Comment: This raises an exception if the string does not contain a hyphen, which, depending on requirements, may be desirable.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix: `string1[0, string1.index('x') || -1]` – passing a negative length result in `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a quick-and-dirty regex.

```
string1 = "1.1.67.01-f9@92a47088f49d095f0"
/^([^-]*)-/ =~ string1
puts $1
```

Let's break down the regular expression

```
/^([^-]*)-/
```

The `/` are the quotation marks of regex, sort of like `"` are for strings. Inside the regex, `^` marks the start of the string and `-` is a literal dash (which terminates our match in this case). Then we have a capture group `(...)`, which indicates that that's the part of the match we're actually *interested* in. Inside, we match any character that is not a dash (`[^-]`), repeated zero or more times (`*`).

After a successful match, we print the first (and, in our case, only) capture group `$1`.

Comment: I don't think you need the beginning-of-string anchor (`\A`) or the capture group and the hyphen should be omitted: `string1[/[^-]*/]`.

Comment: You can feed the regex right into `String#[]` and pass the number of the capture group you want to extract as the 2nd parameter: `string1[/^([^-]*)-/, 1]`

Comment: @Stefan Somehow you made it look *more* like Perl by not using the Perl-style `$1` variables. Impressive :P